# Elsevier cas-sc document class doesn't work properly with XeLatex

Tags: xetex, els-cas

I'm using  `\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}` and I have Arabic text in my article, when I try to execute using XeLatex, it returns this error and displays weired characters in the pdf output.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breakurl/breakurl.sty:311: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \headerps@out 
                         {/burl@stx null def /BU.S { /burl@stx null def } de...
l.311 }
```

This is a minimal code that will reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Al Nile}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=10em, 
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=10em, 
    minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
  decoration={brace},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
}
%%%Author definitions
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}
%%% 
\begin{document}
\let\ref\Cref       
\let\eqref\Cref     
\let\autoref\Cref   
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{CV Radhakrishnan et~al. / Engineering Science and Technology, an International Journal}
\shortauthors{CV Radhakrishnan et~al.}
\footmarks{\url{https://doi.org/xx.xxxx/j.jestch.20xx.xx.xxx}\\
    2215-0986/\begingroup\tiny{©}\endgroup~20xx Karabuk University. Publishing services by Elsevier B.V.\\
    This is an open access article under the CC BY-NC-ND license (\url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/}).
}

\bookmark[named = FirstPage]{This is a specimen $a_b$ title} % Title bookmark used in the pdf
%**************** If the title is short, stay on the first line use [mode = short_title] otherwise ******************
%***************************************** use [mode = title] below ***************************************
\title [mode = short_title]{a title}    


\author[1,3]{CV Radhakrishnan}[type=editor, 
                        auid=000,bioid=1,
                        prefix=Sir,
                        %role=Researcher,
                        %orcid=0000-0001-7511-2910
                        ]
\cormark[1]
%\fnmark[1]                             % URL related footnote marking
\ead{cvr_1@tug.org.in}
\ead[url]{www.cvr.cc, cvr@sayahna.org} % Author URL 

\credit{Conceptualization of this study, Methodology, Software}

\address[1]{Elsevier B.V., Radarweg 29, 1043 NX Amsterdam, The Netherlands}

\author[2,3]{Han Theh Thanh}[style=chinese]

\author[2,3]{CV Rajagopal}[
   %role=Co-ordinator,
   suffix=Jr,
   ]
%\fnmark[2]                             % URL related footnote marking
\ead{cvr3@sayahna.org}
%\ead[URL]{www.sayahna.org}             % Author URL

\credit{Data curation, Writing - Original draft preparation}

\address[2]{Sayahna Foundation, Jagathy, Trivandrum 695014, India}

\author
[1,3]
{Rishi T.} % If the author's name hits "Check for updates" button, use \\ at the break point of his/her name like {\\Rishi T.} or {First Middle\\ Lastname}
% NOTE: Compile first without \\ then the proper separation again afterwards !!! (Not doing so, results unwanted footnote and Credit authorship contribution at the very end with \credit command if used.)
\cormark[2]
%\fnmark[1,3]                           % URL related footnote marking
\ead{rishi@stmdocs.in}


\address[3]{STM Document Engineering Pvt Ltd., Mepukada,
    Malayinkil, Trivandrum 695571, India}

\author[4]{Salih Baris Ozturk} 
\ead{ozturksb@itu.edu.tr}

\address[4]{Istanbul Technical University, Department of Electrical Engineering,
    Maslak, Istanbul 34469, Turkey}

\credit{Modification for the final layout}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.}
\cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author.}
\nonumnote{Peer review under responsibility of Karabuk University.}

\begin{abstract} 
This template helps you to create a properly formatted \LaTeX\ manuscript.

\noindent\texttt{\textbackslash begin{abstract}} \dots 
\texttt{\textbackslash end{abstract}} and
\verb+\begin{keyword}+ \verb+...+ \verb+\end{keyword}+ 
which
contain the abstract and keywords respectively. Each keyword shall be separated by a \verb+\sep+ command. \\
\noindent  \lipsum[1] 

\end{abstract}

\received {xx Month 20xx}
\revised {xx Month 20xx}
\accepted {xx Month 20xx}
\online {xx Month 20xx}

\begin{keywords}
keyword1 \sep
keyword2 \sep
keyword3 \sep

\WGM \sep 
\BEC    
\end{keywords}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
bla bla bla

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}              
\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I comment out `\footmarks`, `\bookmark` and `\online`, changing also `short_title` into `title`, I only get a warning. Please, try and make a *minimal* example that shows the issue.

Comment: you shouldn't use arabtex with xelatex, that style is from 2003 and not suitable for the newer engines.  Apart from this: you are using a five years old texlive.

Comment: @egreg I think there is a problem with the template. I'm using the one available on this link: [link] https://www.elsevier.com/journals/engineering-science-and-technology-an-international-journal/2215-0986/guide-for-authors . Errors occur when compiling even with pdfLatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, I will fix it